# How do I cross-compile Windows software using asio on Linux with CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I wrote some software that uses a serial port to program a radio.  It works just fine under Linux and I suspect it will also work well on Windows, but I'm having some problems compiling it for Windows on Linux.  The project uses CMake and **the non-Boost version of the `asio` library.** I emphasize this to explain why neither boost-centric answers nor the [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio) tag apply here.  I have written and use my own `FindAsio.cmake` file which I have under `cmake/Modules` in my project.

### FindAsio.cmake

```
set(_x86 "(x86)")
file(GLOB _Asio_INCLUDE_DIRS
    "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/asio/*/include"
    "$ENV{ProgramFiles${_x86}}/asio/*/include"
    )
unset(_x86)

find_path(ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES
        asio.hpp
        PATHS
        ${_Asio_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        /usr/include
        /usr/local/include
        ${ASIO_ROOT}
)

if(ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR AND EXISTS "${ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR}/asio/version.hpp")
    file(STRINGS "${ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR}/asio/version.hpp" ASIO_H REGEX "^#define ASIO_VERSION [^/]*/")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*ASIO_VERSION ([0-9]).*$" "\\1" ASIO_VERSION_MAJOR "${ASIO_H}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*ASIO_VERSION [0-9]([0-9][0-9][0-9]).*$" "\\1" ASIO_VERSION_MINOR "${ASIO_H}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*ASIO_VERSION [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9]).*$" "\\1" ASIO_VERSION_PATCH "${ASIO_H}")
    set(ASIO_VERSION "${ASIO_VERSION_MAJOR}.${ASIO_VERSION_MINOR}.${ASIO_VERSION_PATCH}")
endif()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(
    Asio
    DEFAULT_MSG
    ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR
)
```

When I use `mingw64-cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B winbuild` I get an error,

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Asio (missing: ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindAsio.cmake:27 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)
```

Looking into it a bit more, it appears that mingw64 has its own include directory in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include` and, indeed, there is no `asio.hpp` file there.  My package manager, `dnf` (I'm using a Fedora distro) has a number of packages, such as `mingw64-boost` but no `mingw64-asio`.  I could use the boost version of asio, but would really rather not, since I don't actually need any of boost.  The relevant portion of my `src/CMakeLists.txt` file is here:

### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Asio REQUIRED)
add_library(bc95xlt STATIC Channel.cpp Radio.cpp)
target_include_directories(bc95xlt PRIVATE ${ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_compile_definitions(bc95xlt PRIVATE ASIO_STANDALONE)
```

So my question is how to compile my code on Linux for Windows.  Some ideas I had:

1. download the source for asio and put the relevant portions in the mingw64 include tree
2. create symlinks from the mingw64 include directory to the Linux version of asio which is already installed
3. put a local copy of asio in my code tree

What's the way to do this that is easy to maintain?

Comment: "What's the way to do this that is easy to maintain?" - Answers to this question would be mostly *subjective*, and greatly depend on many aspects of your project. We tend to avoid "subjective" questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not at all a subjective question.  It's asking for a concrete suggestion on how to cross compile.  Because ease of maintenance is an important aspect to me, I included it in the question.

Comment: "ease of maintenance is an important aspect to me" - Yes, maintenance is important, but ... maintenance is just **actions** which you expect to do with your project. And you don't describe what actions you **intend** to do! It is not just "how do I want to build the program", but it also about how frequently do you want to update your program, whether do you want to use automatization for that, what kind of automatization and so on. Do you want to build your program against a single version of asio and never update that version? If yes, then just copy the header into your project.

Comment: If I delete that single line, would that improve the question?

Comment: Since that line contains a question, what would be your **question** after deleting it? Is it "how to compile my code on Linux for Windows."? But it seems .. unusual to ask a question and immediately provide possible solutions. In other words, with the last line your question seems clear, but it is not suited for Stack Overflow; without the last line your question is not so clear.

Comment: The question is "how do I compile this program on Linux for Windows?"  which is the title.   Also, it has the line "So my question is how to compile my code on Linux for Windows."  which rephrases it again.  I'm unclear on what you're suggesting I do to improve the question.